# Find nearby places

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, location

I have a function `geoLocate()` that finds a user-inputted location. I would like this function to find a location nearby the user's current location. Can anyone help?

When I call `geoLocate("McDonald's")`, I would like it to find the closest McDonald's relative to the user's location.

```
public void geoLocate(String searchString) throws IOException {
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(searchString, 3);

    if (list.size() > 0) {
        android.location.Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Found: " + locality, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        double lat = add.getLatitude();
        double lng = add.getLongitude();
        gotoLocation(lat, lng, 17);

        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
        }
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().title(locality).position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        marker = mMap.addMarker(options);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No results found for: " + searchString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Find current location for reference:

```
public void setCurrentLocation() {
    try {
        Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
        if (currentLocation == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't connect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
            mMap.animateCamera(update);

            if (myLocationMarker != null) {
                myLocationMarker.remove();
            }
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().title(currentLocation.getLatitude() +
                    ", " + currentLocation.getLongitude()).position(latLng);
            myLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Location not enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have retrieved your current location (latitude, Longitude), You could use the `nearbysearch` of the [Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) to search for McDonnald's like this:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=lat,lon&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=mcdonalds&key=YOUR_API_KEY`. You can actually construct this URL using a `StringBuilder` like this:

```
 StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
 googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
 googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
 googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" + type);
 googlePlacesUrl.append("&name=mcdonalds");
 googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY);
```

You then make an `HTTP` request to the URL using your `HTTP` Client of choice and then process the result (`JSON`). This will return places that match your search, and will include the vicinity of each of these places.

I hope this gives you some ideas on how to proceed. Please give it a try and let me know if it helps.